# how can I avoid extreme when I am trying to plot heatmap of a data

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data is like this

```
df <- structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), level = structure(1:6, .Label = c("B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("118.5328947", "310", "317.0178571", 
"318.3626943", "331.8193548", "95.59670165"), class = "factor"), 
    X3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("100.9557522", 
    "134.0826613", "249.5578231", "293.0097087", "325.3658537", 
    "378.7007042"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("296.0044444", "303.2881356", 
    "317.5611814", "346.3181818", "82.09318498", "89.40270728"
    ), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L), .Label = c("348.9948454", "349.2897959", "355.6374502", 
    "405.5542857", "90.40749698", "98.3877551"), class = "factor"), 
    X6 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("196.7357513", 
    "309.4703557", "315.8136646", "336.9958506", "366.5176471", 
    "404.4050633"), class = "factor"), X7 = structure(c(6L, 1L, 
    4L, 5L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "211.6258503", "236.5221239", 
    "243", "252.682243", "264.2376238"), class = "factor"), X8 = structure(c(6L, 
    5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("210.2341772", "234.25", 
    "254.122093", "41201", "47.33807829", "65.992"), class = "factor"), 
    X9 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("181.825", 
    "236.9159664", "259.5694444", "36.81954887", "37.57967667", 
    "6.260162602"), class = "factor"), X10 = structure(c(6L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("0.675189394", "207.2962963", 
    "218.2409639", "299.8549223", "313.2195122", "42.76348548"
    ), class = "factor"), X11 = structure(c(6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
    2L), .Label = c("1.202247191", "201.6769231", "209.9685535", 
    "226.5793103", "233.1847826", "34.52932551"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"level", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", 
"X11"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I try to plot it, it will give me two colors and ignore the rest of it

```
df$level <- factor(df$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))
levels(melted_cormat$level)
melted_cormat <- melt(df, id = c("time", "level"))
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=level, y=variable, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "yellow")
```

basically I want to be able to somehow show the other values with a smoother color

because when I look at the data, I see an extreme value 41201. I don't want to ignore it but I also want to be able to show the rest of the data

After some search I found that one can set the extreme values to NA and then plot the NA with specific color , is there anyone who can help me with that ?

Comment: maybe you could log transform? It looks a bit better.

Comment: @MLavoie no , I dont want to change the magnitude of the data. It has been changed already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you limit the value and add one more color?

Example:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2) 

df$level <- factor(df$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))

melted_cormat <- melt(df, id = c("time", "level"))

melted_cormat$value <- as.numeric(as.character(melted_cormat$value))

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=level, y=variable, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "yellow",
                                    limits=c(0, 500))
```

[image: Example Plot]

Or using the NA approach:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

df$level <- factor(df$level, levels = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))

melted_cormat <- melt(df, id = c("time", "level"))

melted_cormat$value <- as.numeric(as.character(melted_cormat$value))

melted_cormat$value[melted_cormat$value > 500] <- NA

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=level, y=variable, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "yellow",
                                    na.value = "pink")
```

[image: Second example]

Comment: that is one option, please wait , if I dont get a better answer, I will accept yours or at least I will like it

Comment: @Douglas Adamoski Please note that values outside the `limits` in your first code are replaced by `NA` by default, and you may use `na.value = ` here as well. Thus, there's no real need for an explicit replacement. See `oob` argument in `continuous_scale`.